# Package which provides OpenSSL 1.1.x

Tags: apt, openssl

I'm using ubuntu and need the proxy option in "openssl connect". Does anybody know a way to obtain OpenSSL version 1.1.x via apt-get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsure why this question hasn't been answered.

Dirt simple.

```
apt-get install openssl
```

This will install the latest version of openssl packaged for your Ubuntu version.

You can install higher levels of openssl, doing something like this...

```
apt-get -y install software-properties-common
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2 </dev/null
apt-get update

apt-cache policy openssl

# Now you'll see a higher openssl level... for example...

net10 # apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.1.0h-2.0+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 1.1.0h-2.0+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.0h-2.0+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1.0h-2.0+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/nginx/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.0h-2.0+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.1 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.0g-2ubuntu4 500
        500 http://ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Notice the highest packaged version for Bionic is currently 1.1.0g + latest stable version (from ondrej PPAs) is 1.1.0h, so adding additional PPAs can provide higher level code.

Caveat: Be sure you know what you're doing. If you add the wrong PPA to your system, you can brick your system (brick - can't reboot or start some essential services). Also some PPAs are safe + others are... questionable...

Be sure you understand what you're doing when you add PPAs to your system.